# jquery each only returns first value

Tags: jquery

i would like to go through each person and get the image size. With the height and width i can set the the height and width for the div ".text-person-show".

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".person").each(function () {
        var h = $(this).find(".person-image").height();
        var w = $(this).find(".person-image").width();

        $(this).hover(function () {
            alert(w);
            $(this).find(".person-image").toggle();
            $(this).find(".text-person").toggle();
            $(this).find(".text-person").toggleClass("text-person-show", 'add');
            $(".text-person-show").width(w).height(h);
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="person">
<div class="person-post">
    <div class="person-image">  <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"></div>
        <div class="text-person">
            <div class="text-inner">
                 <div class="name-person-text-inner"><?php the_title(); ?>
                 </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Question is: Why do i get only the alert(w) for the first ".person"?
I don't get right now! variable scope?

Many Thx!!!

Comment: Because that's the intended behaviour of a getter being run on a collection; what did you expect/want to get?

Comment: Whenever I see manual event binding inside a loop I feel ill.

Comment: I like to get the values for each .person

Comment: And where is the relevant HTML? Fiddle will also be great

Comment: Perhaps you have only a single `.person`?

Comment: attach the variable to window..... for example ... window.myVar = "global value"..

Comment: Incidentally, your HTML doesn't have an element with a class-name of `text-person-show` (there's a `text-person`, `text-inner` and `name-person-text-inner`, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code and use .on event for future events and also remove each loop .

```
$(window).load(function () {                    
        $('.person').on('hover', function () {
        var h = $(this).find(".person-image").height();
        var w = $(this).find(".person-image").width();

            alert(w);
            $(this).find(".person-image").toggle();
            $(this).find(".text-person").toggle();
            $(this).find(".text-person").toggleClass("text-person-show", 'add');
            $(".text-person-show").width(w).height(h);
        });
       });
```

Side Note As suggested by  David Thomas:-

> on() has been available in jQuery from version 1.7 (at which point
>   live() was deprecated). In jQuery prior to 1.7 the jQuery team
>   recommended, in the API documentation for the method itself, the use
>   of delegate(). live() has a number of problems (chaining,
>   event-bubbling and performance), and should not be used even where
>   it's available (unless the trade-offs in the documentaiton for the
>   method are acknowledged).

Comment: [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has been available in jQuery from version 1.7 (at which point [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated). In jQuery prior to 1.7 the jQuery team recommended, in the API documentation for the method itself, the use of [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). `live()` has a number of problems (chaining, event-bubbling and performance), and should not be used even where it's available (unless the trade-offs in the documentaiton for the method are acknowledged).

Comment: thanx for information @DavidThomas I have updated answer accordingly